# Add different values(incrementing) to different elements of the same type - LESS CSS

Tags: css, less

I would like to add `"top"` value to different paragraphs in certain class. The thing is that each paragraph has to have different, incremented value like `"top: 30px + something"`, increasing regularly with another paragraph. Paragraphs don't have unique selectors.

```
  .class p{ //1st element
top: 50px;
    }
   .class p{ //2nd element, and so on...
top: 70px;
    }
```

Is there a way to automate this with LESS ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know the number of paragraphs, otherwise isn`t possible for LESS read the HTML. If you know the number of paragraphs you can do a loop and increment the value for each iteration:

**LESS**

```
.paragraphs(4);

.paragraphs(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  .class p:nth-child(@{i}) {
    top: (@i * 20px + 30);
  }
  .paragraphs(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

**Output**

```
.class p:nth-child(1) {
  top: 50px;
}
.class p:nth-child(2) {
  top: 70px;
}
.class p:nth-child(3) {
  top: 90px;
}
.class p:nth-child(4) {
  top: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether LESS or straight CSS, there is no way to say something like

```
parent child:nth-child(n) {
  top: 50px + (10px * n)
}
```

The recommended way to do this would be nesting. A minimal example could look something like

```css
div {
  padding-left: 20px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>first level
    <div>second level
      <div>third level</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course it could be more complex:

```css
div {
  padding-left: 20px
}
```

```html
<div>
  
  <div>
    
    <p>first level</p>
    
    <div>
      
      <p>second level</p>
      
      <div>
        <p>third level</p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

and so on.

Other than that, if you stuck with the

```
<parent>
  <child/>
  <child/>
<parent>
```

model, you could write javascript to walk through your wrapper and apply padding to each child… but that's different from what you're asking

Comment: I don't want use padding at all. I need to add `"top" ` for absolute positioning.  I would be still interested in using LESS, even if I would have to set different ID to paragraphs, but I don't know how to loop and automate it.

Comment: Heh I admit that in the course of writing my answer I forgot you wanted to increase the top spacing, but `top`/`padding-left` etc doesn't make any difference to the solution. I'm going to leave it as padding-left for now, because that's easier to see.

Comment: If you can give each paragraph an `id`, this is easy: `#first {top: 10px} #second {top: 20px} #third {top: 30px}`. And if you have a reasonably small number of elements, @ollin-boer-bohan's method will be fine. But there isn't a way to get the automation you're hoping for without a script

Comment: I guess I can do it manually as you suggest, but I was hoping that it could be done better with some kind of looping via LESS.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this manually for a finite number of elements as

```
.class p:nth-child(1) { //1st element
    top: 50px;
}
.class p:nth-child(2) { //2nd element, and so on...
    top: 70px;
}
```

However there is no way for LESS to know in advance how many children the page will contain, so it can't auto-generate all of these.  You would have to write them yourself (as above) or reposition elements in JavaScript once the page has loaded.

I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve here, but it seems like it might be better resolved by using static positioning methods (rather than absolute positioning) and allowing fixed-height `<p>` elements to push each other downward within the container, rather than absolutely positioning them at intervals.